# Structural directive with dynamic variable within

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

In angular I created structural directive that hides DOM according to screen width (`appUkryj` is `appHide` in english):

```js
import {Directive, Input, OnInit, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';
import {AppBreakpoints, BreakpointService} from '@app/utils/ui/breakpoint.service';
import {UnsubscribeOnDestroy} from '@app/utils/unsubscribe-on-destroy.interface';
import {debounceTime, takeUntil, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appUkryj]'
})
export class UkryjDirective extends UnsubscribeOnDestroy implements OnInit {
  private _breakpoint: AppBreakpoints = AppBreakpoints.MD;
  private _hasView: boolean = false;
  private staleWidoczny: boolean = true;

  private zmienWidocznoscSubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  @Input() set appUkryj(value: string) {
    if (value) {
      switch (value) {
        case 'sm':
          this._breakpoint = AppBreakpoints.SM;
          break;
        case 'md':
          this._breakpoint = AppBreakpoints.MD;
          break;
        case 'lg':
          this._breakpoint = AppBreakpoints.LG;
          break;
        case 'xl':
          this._breakpoint = AppBreakpoints.XL;
          break;
        case 'hd':
          this._breakpoint = AppBreakpoints.HD;
          break;
        default:
          this._breakpoint = AppBreakpoints.MD;
          break;
      }
    } else {
      this._breakpoint = AppBreakpoints.MD;
    }
    this.applyChanges();
  }

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private breakpointService: BreakpointService,
  ) {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.applyChanges();
  }

  private applyChanges(): void {
    try {
      const el = this.templateRef.elementRef.nativeElement.parentElement;
      if (el.classList.contains('btn')) {
        el.onmouseenter = () => {
          if (!this.staleWidoczny) {
            this.zmienWidocznoscSubject.next(true);
          }
        };
        el.onmouseleave = () => {
          if (!this.staleWidoczny) {
            this.zmienWidocznoscSubject.next(false);
          }
        };
      }
    } catch (e) {
    }

    this.zmienWidocznoscSubject.asObservable()
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$), debounceTime(500))
      .subscribe(resp => {
        if (!this.staleWidoczny) {
          this.embedTemplate(resp);
        }
      });
    this.breakpointService.isLessThen(this._breakpoint)
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.destroy$),
        tap(resp => {
          this.staleWidoczny = !resp;
        })
      )
      .subscribe(resp => {
        this.embedTemplate(!resp);
      });
  }

  private embedTemplate(enabled): void {
    if (enabled && !this._hasView) {
      this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
      this._hasView = true;
    } else if (!enabled && this._hasView) {
      this.viewContainerRef.clear();
      this._hasView = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Problem is when I have dynamic variables within like `<span *appUkryj="'lg'">{{label}}</span>`. `label` is always empty. How to fix it?